# Fullscreen camera in iPhone 5s

Tags: iphone, ios7, camera, fullscreen

I create a camera overlay with a custom view and i m trying to have the camera in fullscreen by applying scale and translation. It work great in iPhone 5 but it doesn't in iPhone 5s. I try many portions of codes but still not found the problem. This is my code :

```
if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568) {
    CGAffineTransform translate = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, 71.0);
    CGAffineTransform scale = CGAffineTransformScale(translate, 1.333333, 1.333333);
    imagePicker.cameraViewTransform = scale;
}
```

By the way i do my tests in iOS 7.

Thank's for help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

put this line of code in your custom camera oveylay class. It works for me in iPhone5s.

```
        CGSize screenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;

        int heightOffset = 120;

        float cameraAspectRatio = 4.0 / 3.0; //! Note: 4.0 and 4.0 works
        float imageWidth = floorf(screenSize.width * cameraAspectRatio);
        float scale = ceilf(((screenSize.height + heightOffset) / imageWidth) * 10.0) / 10.0;

        self.imagePickerController.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scale, scale);
```

Comment: Hi. Thank u for your replay but it still not working. i add an image to see the rendering. What i don t undertand is that it s working in iPhone 5 and not in 5s even they have the same size.